Export an animation to a sprite sheet
The game engine I use only has support for 2D images, but i still want to have a 3D artstyle. Is there a way to export a blender animation into a single image, split into each frame?

Like this, but in 3D.

If you mean a single image for each frame, certainly. Just select the correct File Format on the R/H panel Output Properties > Output dropdown. You'll then have an image for each frame in the output folder after rendering the animation.

I think you’re better off rendering the individual frames, and then joining them together with Python or something externally.

Thank you! I'm sure there's a python script out there that will combine frames. Will the export still have transparency?
